# How to link source from outside of maven project?

Tags: maven-2

In Maven, is it possible to link additional dependent java src from outside the project folders, so that when we build our main package, maven may include such classes into final jar?
just as we can link any source folder to our project in Eclipse and eclipse treats it as regular project source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In Maven, is it possible to link additional dependent java src from outside the project folders

Technically, it's possible to add source folders to a build and this is usually done using the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html). However, I would recommend against doing so for directories **outside** a given module, a maven module should be self contained.

Comment: Thank you for your help and specially for the recommendation.

Comment: I tried what you linked but it's not working for me. I repeatedly receive compile/package errors because it doesn't find any external packages (from my external source linked folder)