# How to link source from outside of maven project and use that linked source for further development.?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, pom.xml, m2eclipse

My question is similar to [link source using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125306/how-to-link-source-from-outside-of-maven-project).

If I follow the above question's answer I can have some extra classes in my final war file that will be generated by maven.

But my requirement is that, my IDE(Eclipse) should treat it as an additional source in the current project. So I will have an additional source folder(Not added manually). This additional source contains some common classes that will be used by current project.

Here I don't want to add this source folder manually. Let maven do the work, so that I will be having an additional source for some common classes and the same source classes in war too.

Can anybody help.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check which Eclipse version you use and which m2e version your are using. It should work out of the box. Does your build work on command line without any issue?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Kepler 4.3 SR2 and m2e version is 1.4.0.20130601. Sorry I am not familiar with maven command line executions, because I am using m2e plugin in Eclipse.

Comment: You should run your build on command line first if it works than go into your IDE....

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments @khmarbaise. I will try to build and will let you know..

Answer (score 1):

for adding source you can use the following tags

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>file.repo</id>
        <url>file://url/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

or you can also add

```
<pluginRepositories>
     <pluginRepository>
           <id></id>
           <name></name>
           <url>*your source*</url>
           <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
           <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
     </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Will not work, cause repositories are for binary resources or in other words already compiled and packaged artifacts which are `jar` files.

Comment: can't we use something like the following.
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>file.repo</id>
        <url>file://url/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried the above code..but not working..Can you provide any other method @khmarbaise ..?